# django-simple-history, TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/shared_models/mannedsetting/1/history/ simple_history/object_history.html

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I am using django-history-admin

I have model class

```
class MannedSetting(BaseModel):
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_manned_setting'
    confirm_msg = m.CharField(max_length=400)
```

then in admin.py

```
from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin
class MannedSettingAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = ["id","confirm_msg"]
admin.site.register(MannedSetting,MannedSettingAdmin)
```

There appears the history button in the edit page of `MannedSetting` instance

However when clicking the button, this error comes.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/shared_models/mannedsetting/1/history/
simple_history/object_history.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8010/admin/shared_models/mannedsetting/1/history/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
simple_history/object_history.html
Exception Location: /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/cinnamon-admin-mg9y4sUV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/cinnamon-admin-mg9y4sUV/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/s_cdk/myadmin',
 '/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/s_cdk/myadmin/my-shared-models',
 '/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/s_cdk/myadmin/$PYTHONPATH',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/cinnamon-admin-mg9y4sUV/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 12 Feb 2022 22:24:06 +0900
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs if you forget to add `simple_history` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the project's settings during setup

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'simple_history',
]
```

You can find the installation instructions on the project [Quick Start here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick_start.html#configure)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33078385)